# How to get post parameters values from webview URL in webview android

Tags: android, webview

After third party payment, I got a success URL with POST parameters from the payment gateway URL over WebView. Here I need those parameters. 
Here is my code:

```
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                                        if (mWebView.getUrl().contains("https://www.digital.in/payment")) {
                                            responseUrl = mWebView.getUrl();
                                            String cmp = responseUrl.substring(0, 38);
                                            if (cmp.contains("https://www.digital.in/payment"))
                                                getPaymentStatus();

                                        }
                                        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                                    }
                                }
    );
```

//here I want to get post params from responseUrl before getPaymentStatus()

Comment: Urls never contain post parameters. And you did not tell where those parameters should come from. Or why there are any.

Comment: @blackapps After third party payment, I got a success URL with POST parameters from the payment gateway URL over WebView. Here I need those parameters